# Django how ImageField and BinaryField works for image

Tags: django, image, django-rest-framework

So i wanted to ask how does these 2 fields works.
As my friend told me that his ios will sent byte format image to me, does it matter if i use imageField instead of BinaryField ?

I did try adding a Binaryfield into my User models but when testing it out on django admin and also django rest framework api, it doenst work

In django admin : the binaryfield did not appear in it

In django rest framework : got an error that says editable is false for binary field. Setting the binaryfield editable=True also doesnt work.

The documentation about Binaryfield in django is also not much.

Can anyone please explain to me how does these 2 field work ? does sending byte format to the imagefield work ?

Answer (score 3):

The ImageField takes care of pictures. Otherwise, ImageField and FileField are the same. Both store the path to a file of the pysical volume.
And both do not meet the requirements.
The database requires a BinaryField:

```
models.BinaryField (blank = true, null = true, editable = true)
```

So far so good. With editable = True, the field should appear in the admin interface. But to see the picture, it has to be transformed again before

```
encoded = b64encode (model.image) .decode ('ascii')
```

and e.g. poured into a form.

```
render_to_string ('lib / forms / imageform.html', {"image": encoded}, request).
```

The form element in my case looks like this:

```
<form id = "{{form.fid}}" class = "form-horizontal data-form" enctype = "multipart / form-data" method = "post">
     <img src = "data: image / png; base64, {{image}}">
</ Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ImageField` or `FileField` is what you should use to save images. Both of these fields just save the file_path (Ex: /static/user_images/smith.jpg) to the physical image stored on the server. 
For more detail read this [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield)  and [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

`BinaryField` not used to save images.  [For more detail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

**Note** : that you never store a physical file to a Database. That is you don't use `BinaryField` for images.

Comment: i know , but my teammate says the image sent to me is in byte format. Just wonder does Imagefield or filefield works on it or not. and if these 2 field save the file path, does that means its not saving the image to database ? isnt that bad?

Comment: Usually image is not stored to database . I am not certain in which case some one saves image to data base.

Comment: ok, so the byte file will be save into file path in aws. Though, what field to use ? Because i am not saving the image directly, Its saving the byte string. I am only converting it into image when user request for it

Comment: You can use `FileField` to save any physical file, which will save the path to it , in database

Comment: Sorry Amar, but i have to double check this first.
I am storing byte string, not physical file. Does it still work on `FileField`?
This is what confuse me the most as only `ImageField` and `FileField` are the only one with save to path function.

Comment: If you are not storing physical file and you want to store raw byte then use `BinaryField`